# Decode nested JSON as string using JSONDecoder()

Tags: swift, swift5

I have a JSON data structure representing Animals. e.g.:

```
{
"id": "3",
"type": "dog",
"properties": {
        "tail_color": "black",
        "paw_color": "white"
    }
}

{
"id": "5",
"type": "fish",
"properties": {
        "fin_color": "black",
        "num_teeth": "3"
        "max_speed": "27"
    }
}
```

`id` and `type` are consistent for all animals but the keys within `properties` change depending on `type`.

I want to parse these animals into `struct AnimalModel`. Because `properties` is inconsistent, I want to store this sub-json as string (and process it later):

```
struct AnimalModel: Identifiable, Codable {
    let id: String
    let type: String
    let properties: String // JSON, content and keys depending on type
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id
        case type
        case properties
    }

}

// data .. JSON-string
guard let newAnimal = try? JSONDecoder().decode(AnimalModel.self, from: data) else {
                    return
                }
```

The `JSONDecoder()` however fails here. How can I parse properties as string into `AnimalModel`?

Comment: `properties` is a dictionary, can't you decode it into [String: String] instead?

Comment: Start by doing a property `do`/`try`/`catch` instead of silencing the thrown error with `try?`. It should throw an error explaining why your decoding fail...

Comment: Where is `type`? If the properties are consistent for each type use an enum with associated values.

Comment: yes, type is there, was a typo. That wasn't the issue. Updated the post

Comment: [String: String] works, thank you @JoakimDanielson

Comment: properties could still be more complex, e.g. some containing lists, some not. Is it possible to parse the properties "sub-json" to string?

Comment: Either create custom struct per `type` as mentioned or if you decode objects only by one as in the sample code then keep the whole json string (data) in a property, this is probably easier than trying to store a part of the json message